# ORA-04098: trigger is invalid and failed re-validation due to compilations error

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle12c

My below trigger is giving 2 compilations error and I think due to which I am getting error ORA-04098: trigger  is invalid and failed re-validation from application.

```
create or replace TRIGGER delete_ks_after_STEP_LP_to_AV
  BEFORE UPDATE OF status_cd
  ON SUPER.work_order_steps
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN ( new.status_cd in ('AV','PE') and old.status_cd='LP' and old.mml_operation_cd is not null and old.step_def_code in ('CMA','CMM','CID'))  
BEGIN

insert into knowledge_session_tidy  select distinct knowledge_session_uid ,sysdate from knowledge_session_history where 
knowledge_session_uid in (select knowledge_session_uid from prov_knowledge_session_use a where a.wo_no=:new.wo_no
and a.seq_no=:new.seq_no and
NOT EXISTS (select 1 from knowledge_session_tidy b where a.knowledge_session_uid =b.knowledge_session_uid)));

Delete from knowledge_session where 
knowledge_session_uid in (select knowledge_session_uid from prov_knowledge_session_use where wo_no=:new.wo_no
and seq_no=:new.seq_no); 

END delete_ks_after_STEP_LP_to_AV;
```

compilations error is as below

```
Errors for TRIGGER delete_ks_after_STEP_LP_to_AV:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -------------------------------------------------
3/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

6/108    PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a superfluous closing bracket (line #23 in my reformatted code; I prefer to see exactly what's what and which bracket matches which other bracket):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger delete_ks_after_step_lp_to_av before
  2    update of status_cd on work_order_steps
  3    for each row
  4    when(    new.status_cd in ('AV', 'PE')
  5         and old.status_cd = 'LP'
  6         and old.mml_operation_cd is not null
  7         and old.step_def_code in ('CMA', 'CMM', 'CID')
  8        )
  9  begin
 10    insert into knowledge_session_tidy
 11      select distinct knowledge_session_uid,
 12                      sysdate
 13      from knowledge_session_history
 14      where knowledge_session_uid in (select knowledge_session_uid
 15                                      from prov_knowledge_session_use a
 16                                      where a.wo_no = :new.wo_no
 17                                        and a.seq_no = :new.seq_no
 18                                        and not exists (select 1
 19                                                        from knowledge_session_tidy b
 20                                                        where a.knowledge_session_uid = b.knowledge_session_uid
 21                                                       )
 22                                     );
 23  -- );        superfluous closing bracket
 24    delete from knowledge_session
 25    where knowledge_session_uid in (select knowledge_session_uid
 26                                    from prov_knowledge_session_use
 27                                    where wo_no = :new.wo_no
 28                                      and seq_no = :new.seq_no
 29                                   );
 30  end delete_ks_after_step_lp_to_av;
 31  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks , it sorted the issue it was related to bracket only